# Wildfly 26 changed behaviour of REST with content type "x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly

while updating from Wildfly version 24 to version 26 I found an anoying change within REST.

If I post with curl some data, it is just not received on the server. I already found out, that this is because of default content type "x-www-form-urlencoded", used by curl.

Example server code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

@Stateless
@Path("test")
public class RestSample {

    @POST
    @Path("t1")
    public Response postData(InputStream dataInputStream) {
        String content=null;
        try {
            content=IOUtils.toString(dataInputStream,"UTF-8");
            System.out.println("content length: "+content.length());
            System.out.println("content: "+content);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An exception occurred."+e);
        }

        return Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED).entity("Received: "+content).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("t2")
    public String postData(String input) {
        return "Received: "+input;
    }

}
```

Both methods `postData()` do the same and react the same. The first one is working more low level with InputStream and Response, but we can focus on the second one, which is really simple: The received content becomes part of the response.

If I do start my **Wildfly 24** and do the call:

```
curl -d "Hello World" http://localhost/server/rest/test/t2
```

I see the response:

```
Received: Hello World
```

The same if I call:

```
curl -d "Hello World" -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' http://localhost/server/rest/test/t2
```

I see the response:

```
Received: Hello World
```

But if I use the same code within **Wildfly 26**, the behaviour changes:

```
curl -d "Hello World" -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' http://localhost/server/rest/test/t2
```

This still works and returns:

```
Received: Hello World
```

But:

```
curl -d "Hello World" http://localhost/server/rest/test/t2
```

Now gets an empty input stream or empty string and I just get:

```
Received:
```

So, the question is:
What has changed? Is ther a chance to get back the old behaviour?

## Update:

This is really strange! I apologize for not testing my code on a ‘clear’ Wildfly! As James mentioned: There it is working, but I did simply not expect such side effects!

I compared my productive system with the clear test system a long time and compared e. g.

- standalone.xml
- modules folder
- web.xml
- application.xml
- adding primefaces-11.0.1.jar

And I only found out one thing: If I remove the `<login-config>` section from my web.xml in my productive software, the problem is away. But if I put this section within my clean test system, it still works!

So it looks like the problem is based on multiple components but I do not find anything else. So, I found a workaround for the `<login-config>` section and hope there are no other problems from the same source.

Comment: What if you add the normal `Consumes` to the methods?  As it is you're telling Wildfly it'll accept anything.

Comment: Already tested. But my problem is not, that my code is not called (which would be configured with consumes). My problem is that my method is called, so I consume the "x-www-form-urlencoded" message but I do not get the data!

Comment: What does your configuration look like? I cannot reproduce this. I see "Response: Hello World" with all requests.

Comment: Thanks James for the try to reproduce. OK, in this case I have to dig deeper, because there are so many configuration options!
I will come back with more information as soon as I have them.

Comment: I compare a product with 10 years development with a complete new example.
The `standalone.xml`, the modules folder and the `faces-config.xml` seems not to be the problem.
I found within `web.xml` that I use `<login-confg>`. If I remove this, the product works again (beside nice login). But If I take over this `<login-confg>` to my small example, it still works! So, there seems to be another component of the problem, but I do not know where.
Which configs could I check? Has anyone any idea?

Comment: I'm not too sure TBH. There was a major RESTEasy upgrade done in WildFly 25, but I'm not sure how the login-config would cause that issue. Definitely strange though.

Comment: Thanks again James. Well, currently I do have a workaround. Maybe someone else finds the issue and it will be fixed during the next versions or I will find another problem giving me more information about the source. Let's see.